# Live-action Norwegian movie about man whose job is to monitor troll migration

Tags: story-identification, movie, trolls

I do not quite remember the beginning but somehow two teenagers, brother and sister get lost in woods of Northern Norway. They run into a man who studies trolls and monitors their migration. Together they go through a series of adventures until they cross path with a troll that is affected with rabies and finally that all ends up badly (the end of the movie is nebulous, but you got lasting impression that it did not go well).

The trolls looked like a giant humanoid beings, hairy and almost brainless. There were different trolls, but they all lived in isolation from each other. It was summer time.

I watched it something like ten years ago. I mentioned it when talking to my wife and she said she wanted to watch it. But I can't remember its title.

Comment: *"The trolls looked like a giant humanoid beings, hairy and almost brainless"* More precisely, they looked ***exactly*** like [classic Kittelsen illustrations](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&sca_esv=594376342&q=kittelsen+troll&tbm=isch) brought to life - each individual troll would be recognisable to anyone who grew up on Norwegian fairy tales.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This might be the 2010 movie [*Troll Hunter*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1740707/).

Quoting from the surprisingly complete [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trollhunter):

> A group of students from Volda University College, Thomas (Glenn Erland Tosterud), Johanna (Johanna Mørck) and their cameraman Kalle (Tomas Alf Larsen), set out to make a documentary about a suspected bear poacher, Hans (Otto Jespersen). At the site of an illegally slain bear they interview local hunters, who comment that the bear tracks look odd, as well as Finn Haugen (Hans Morten Hansen), head of the Norwegian Wildlife Board. Finn dismisses the idea that the bear tracks could have been faked. The students follow Hans in an attempt to secure an interview but he continually rebuffs them. After following him into a forest at night time, they see mysterious flashing lights and hear roars. Hans comes running back, screaming "Troll!" Thomas is attacked and reveals that he was bitten by something. They escape in Hans's Land Rover and discover their own vehicle turned over with the tyres ripped off. Hans admits that it is not bears he is hunting, but trolls. Though sceptical, the students ask if they can join Hans and film his hunt, to which he consents on the condition that they do exactly as he instructs.

Various adventures happen, one of the students is killed, and then after the massive "Jotnar" is killed, the students are disappeared by the secret TSS organization.

The trolls are infected with rabies:

> Thomas falls ill, and they learn that **the troll blood sample came back positive for rabies**, meaning Thomas has been infected by the bite he received several days earlier.

Comment: Yes, I this is it. It seems my memory let me down a little. Thank you very much.